# Overriding a sealed trait in Scala

Tags: scala, overriding, traits

I am using a library that has a sealed trait.
I really need to extend this trait.

Is there a way (even a dirty one) to bypass that?

For a bit of background, this is what I am trying to work around : https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues/247

Comment: that would totally destroy the semantic of a `sealed trait`, so I believe - and frankly hope - there is no way.

Comment: `sealed` is a Scala semantic, other languages can extend `sealed trait`s just fine. Now, whether that is a good idea, is a different matter ;-)

Comment: Well I was looking for a hack really. It is either that or I recompile their source without the sealed...

Answer (score 6):

Don't extend, include, *If you need to consider another option.*

```
// Foo.scala
sealed trait Foo
case class Foo1(n: Int) extends Foo
case class Foo2(s: String) extends Foo

// Bar.scala
sealed trait Bar
case class BarFoo(foo: Foo) extends Bar
case class Bar3(b: Boolean) extends Bar
```

And the boilerplate can be reduced by implicit conversion

```
implicit def fooToBar(foo: Foo): Bar = BarFoo(foo)
```

---

Or *if you want to add new methods to an existing class*, use implicit classes:

```
// Foo.scala
sealed trait Foo
case class Foo1(n: Int) extends Foo
case class Foo2(s: String) extends Foo

// Quux.scala
// This class be called FooOps or FooExtra, if you like, name is irrelevant
implicit class Quux(foo: Foo) {
  def quux: Boolean = foo match {
    case Foo1(n) => n == 0
    case Foo2(s) => s.isEmpty
  }
}
```

Then you can use `.quux` on `Foo` values:

```
scala> Foo1(2).quux
res1: Boolean = false

scala> Foo2("").quux
res2: Boolean = true
```

This is about the same as extending, but with even less boilerplate, compare to:

```
case class Quux2(foo: Foo) {
  def quux2: Boolean = foo match {
    case Foo1(n) => n == 0
    case Foo2(s) => s.isEmpty
  }
}

implicit def fooToQuux2(foo: Foo): Quux2 = Quux2(foo)

scala> Foo1(2).quux
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Foo2("").quux
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I need to extend because then I am using an API that needs a Foo